# Pandas.read_sql_query reads int as float

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am exporting SQL database into `csv` using `Pandas.read_sql_query` + `df.to_csv` and have a problem that integer fields are represented as float in DataFrame.

My code:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(server, port)
chunk = pandas.read_sql_query('''select * from table''', conn)

df = pandas.DataFrame(chunk)    # here int values are float
df.to_csv()
```

I am exporting a number of tables this way and the problem is that `int` fields are exported as `float` (with a dot). Also, I don't know upfront which column has which type (code supposed to be generic for all tables)

However, my target is to export **everything as is - in strings**

The things I've tried (without a success):

1. `df.applymap(str)`
2. `read_sql_query(coerce_float=False)`
3. `df.fillna('')`
4. `DataFrame(dtype=object)` / `DataFrame(dtype=str)`

Of course, I can then post-process the data to type-cast integers, but would be better to do it during the initial import

UPD: My dataset has `NULL` values. They should be replaced with empty strings (as the purpose is to typecast all columns to strings)

Comment: Does your SQL integer columns have `NULL` values? Pandas coerces them to `np.nan`, which is a float, which in turn coerces the whole column to a float dtype. If that's the issue, "manually" coercing the column back to integer after the initial import is likely your best alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a solution by post-processing the data (force converting to strings) using applymap:

```
def convert_to_int(x):
    try:
        return str(int(x))
    except:
        return x
df = df.applymap(convert_to_int)
```

The step takes significant time for processing, however solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

Pandas infers the datatype from a sample of the data. If an integer column has null values, pandas assigns it the float datatype because NaN is of float type and because pandas is based on numpy which has no nullable integer type. So try making sure that you dont have any nulls or that nulls are replaced with 0's if it makes sense in your dataset, 0 being an integer.

ALSO, another way to go about this would be to specify the dtypes on data import, but you have to use a special kind of integer, like Int64Dtype, [as per the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na):

```
"If you need to represent integers with possibly missing values, use one of the nullable-integer extension dtypes provided by pandas"
```

Comment: I've updated the question. Table has Null values, but they should be ignored. I.e. import has to be robust enough to get everything as strings (Null - empty string)

Comment: I've also updated my answer, if you use a nullable integer dtype it should work.